# How to get the constraint part of a generic method as a text by Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

How to get the constraint part of a generic method as a text by `IMethodSymbol`?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Student> Get<T, V>(V v, T t)
    where T : class, ICloneable, new()
    where V : struct
{
    return null;
}
```

I want to get the below result

```
    where T: class, ICloneable, new()
    where V: struct
```

Comment: Have a look at the properties on [`ITypeParameterSymbol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.itypeparametersymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet), e.g. `ConstraintTypes` and `HasConstructorConstraint` and `HasValueTypeConstraint`

Comment: So, I have no access to the text directly like ClassDeclarationSyntax.ConstraintClauses.ToFullString() Yes? I should create the source text with those properties.

Comment: Oh, you're looking at the syntax, not the symbols? It's worth specifying in your question. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNGAfAAgJgIwCwAUFgAwAEWeALANzFYDMlO5AwuQN7Hm+XNUAbJTyMAPAGUYAVwAmcAHYwAfOQDicGGIAqScgDVlACn3kAbnu3kYASh58HAdwAWiOOSsgWegJJsANgD2CnAQwP5weiGORnZEDk6uCO6mXrAI0gDGMPa83PEJvFgA7OQK0v7+9AW8AL7E9UQMAqxScoowXOS1QA), in particular the `TypeParameterConstraintClause`